# How to retrieve value of radio button and insert into database in code igniter?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter-2

I have a  form  named feedback.php with two questions.I want to retreat the value of selected radio button and insert into database in code igniter. The table name is 'feedback'  where i am storing  this values.
html code for form is here

```
<form role="form" method="post" name ="your_form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/feedback_model/index" >
           <span class="badge">1</span></a> Is your complain solved ?  
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="Question1"          
value="yes">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="Question1" value="no">NO</label>
            </div>
        </div>  


         <span class="badge">2</span></a> How easy was it to complain to us?  
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="Question2" value='excellent'>Excellent</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="Question2" value="good">Good </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="Question2" value="bad">Bad</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="Question2" value="verybad">Very Bad</label>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </form>
```

In controller i have feedback.php with this code

```
 <?php
class feedback_model extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('feedback_model');
}
function index()
{
// Including Validation Library



// Setting Values For Tabel Columns
$data = array(
'complain_id' => $this->input->post('complain_id'),
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
'response1' => $this->input->post('Qustion1'),
 'response1' => $this->input->post('Question2'),
 'response1' => $this->input->post('Question3'),
 'response1' => $this->input->post('Question4')

);
// Transfering Data To Model
$this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
// Loading View
$this->load->view('feedback');
}
}
?>
```

And in model i have feedback_model.php with this code.

```
<?php
class feedback_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}
function form_insert($data){
// Inserting in Table(feedback) of Database(college)
$this->db->insert('feedback', $data);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: How your form date enter into controller file???

Comment: thats the thning i want to know .  i am new in codeigniter.

Comment: You should add the `method="post"` attribute to your `form`tag

Comment: I have added post method  now i want to know how to  find the value of selected radio button in code igniter and pass it to database??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created same something like yours

First is you need to setup your project properly
Like Database Connection, Autoloaded Helpers of CI

Here is my feedback.php controller

```
<?php

class feedback extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('feedback_model');
    }

    function index() {
        
        // Loading View
        $this->load->view('feedback');
    }

    function submit() {

        // check for method
        if ($this->input->post('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {

            // Including Validation Library
            // Setting Values For Tabel Columns
            $data = array(
                'response1' => $this->input->post('Qustion1'),
                'response2' => $this->input->post('Question2')
            );

            // Transfering Data To Model
            $this->feedback_model->form_insert($data);
        }

        
    }
}
```

Here is my feedback_model.php nothings really change with yours

```
<?php

class feedback_model extends CI_Model{

    function form_insert($data){
        // Inserting in Table(feedback) of Database(college)
        $this->db->insert('feedback', $data);
    }
}
```

Here is the view, named as feedback.php under the folder views

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form role="form" method="POST" action="feedback/submit">
      <span class="badge">1</span></a> Is your complain solved ?
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="Question1"
          value="yes">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="Question1" value="no">NO</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="badge">2</span></a> How easy was it to complain to us?
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="Question2" value='excellent'>Excellent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="Question2" value="good">Good </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="Question2" value="bad">Bad</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="Question2" value="verybad">Very Bad</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the view i added a attribute

> method="POST" and action="feedback/submit"

method means the request type going to the server
and action is uri your form being submitted

so in this case the form will be submitted to controller feedback where the
method is submit

from the submit method

i check if the request method is post

and get the post data namely the

> Question1
>
> Question2

and pass it to the feedback_model

```
$data = array(
    'response1' => $this->input->post('Qustion1'),
    'response2' => $this->input->post('Question2')
);

// Transfering Data To Model
$this->feedback_model->form_insert($data);
```

you can modified it according to your need.

and one more thing that is important is the naming conventions for MVC

since you have a controller feedback_model.php then created again a feedback_model.php for model which is confusing.

Hope it help

Comment: @RahulSingh have you already solve it, I am using pretty url, using htaccess and mod_rewrite to remove the index.php

Answer (score 1):

You form data is not submit because you not write `action` in form tag

```
 <form role="form" method="post" name ="your_form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/feedback_model/index" >
```

And you get your radio button data in your controller

```
function index()
{
// Setting Values For Table Columns
$data = array(
'complain_id' => $this->input->post('complain_id'),
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
'response1' => $this->input->post('Qustion2'),// you radio button data
'response2' => $this->input->post('Qustion1'),
);
// Transfering Data To Model
$this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
// Loading View
$this->load->view('feedback',$data);

}
```

No any input type having name this in your form

```
$this->input->post('Question2')
$this->input->post('Question3')
```

Comment: after submitting form i m getting an error of page not found.

Comment: i have remove that code from html form because the concept will be same for all of them.